# Tom Riddle level missing?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-1-4

I have Lego Harry Potter on the X-Box. I opened it recently and I noticed something I didn't see before. For year 2, the "Tom Riddle's Diary"(level 4 or 5 of the year) seems to b missing, although I have completed all the levels before and after it. I tried finishing the previous level to see it I can access it, but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how to access this level?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks